# Convert readAsBinaryString() results back to Binary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

After converting a File to a BinaryString in HTML5 via the FileReader readAsBinaryString() method, is there a way to convert the data back to binary in JavaScript?

Comment: Can you clarify by giving some relevant code snippets?

Comment: if you're familiar with the html5 spec, it's pretty straight forward. here's a link to code that looks just like mine. http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-slicing-files